# In AutoMapper 8.0 missing ResolveUsing

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper

Prior to AutoMapper 8.0, I have used this code:

```
CreateMap<ApplicationRole, RoleViewModel>()
.ForMember(d => d.Permissions, map => map.MapFrom(s => s.Claims))
.ForMember(d => d.UsersCount, map => map.ResolveUsing(s => s.Users?.Count ?? 0))
                    .ReverseMap();
```

The documentation says that you have to change ResolveUsing for MapFrom, but I have a Error "No propagation Null"

```
.ForMember(d => d.UsersCount, map => map.MapFrom(s => s.Users?.Count ?? 0))
```

How I have to resolve it?

Comment: Make sure you supply the _full_ error message, including any stacktraces if such a thing exists for you.

Comment: As the docs say, you need a Func based overload, as opposed to the Expression based ones. http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#existing-resolveusing-usages

Comment: You can simply remove the ResolveUsing(or MapFrom) and it will be mapped by convention Users.Count=>UsersCount.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Replace ResolveUsing with MapFrom, and add one more input parameter to the lambda (TDestination).

```
.ForMember(d => d.UsersCount, map => map.MapFrom((s,d) => s.Users?.Count ?? 0))
```

EDIT November 2022

Newest version(s) of AutoMapper doesn't support lambda expression in MapFrom. In this case you have to extract it to a method (Func) or do it inline if you can.
Also, null propagation isn't allowed unless it's a method.

```
.ForMember(d => d.UsersCount, map => map.MapFrom(s => MapUserCount(s))
--------------
private static int MapUserCount(ApplicationRole src) {
    return src.Users?.Count ?? 0;
}
```

or

```
.ForMember(d => d.UsersCount, map => map.MapFrom(s => s.Users == null ? 0 : s.Users.Count))
```

Answer (score 21):

[In AutoMapper 8.0 missing ResolveUsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637653/in-automapper-8-0-missing-resolveusing#new-answer)

I also have the same issue and I'm using the following prototype of `ResolveUsing`:

```
void ResolveUsing(Func<TSource, TResult> mappingFunction);
```

Instead of replacing existing code, I preferred to create an extension method:

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;

namespace myLibrary.Extensions
{
    public static class AutoMapperCompatibilityExtensions
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Resolve destination member using a custom value resolver callback. Used instead
        //     of MapFrom when not simply redirecting a source member This method cannot be
        //     used in conjunction with LINQ query projection
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   resolver:
        //     Callback function to resolve against source type
        public static void ResolveUsing<TSource, TDestination, TMember, TResult>(this IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination, TMember> member, Func<TSource, TResult> resolver) => member.MapFrom((Func<TSource, TDestination, TResult>)((src, dest) => resolver(src)));
    }
}
```

Later, in my code, I simply referred the namespace:

```
using myLibrary.Extensions;

...
    ... map.ResolveUsing(s =>  ...
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please forgive me, can I kindly know why I get -1 on this answer? Thanks.

Comment: Well I just gave you a +1 because if a library does not maintain backward compatibility it is perfectly reasonable to do it yourself.

Comment: This saved my day

Comment: Excellent idea!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use this expression, you can "Users.Count" and it'll return 0 if the list is empty.

Comment: This answer ignores the fact that the poster probably has a more complex scenario but needed to post something simpler to demonstrate the problem.